# React props.auth.user is undifined when registering a user

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

In my project when I try to print the name of the user that just registered it shows undifined.

When I register a user he is redirected to the dashboard page where is name should apear but it doesn´t. But when I reload the page the name shows correctly.

The login is done similiar to register but works fine.

My component to register bidder.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { registerBidder } from "../../actions/auth";
import { createMessage } from "../../actions/messages";
export class RegisterBidder extends Component {
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    password2: "",
    first_name: "",
    last_name: "",
    aluno: "false"
  };

  static propTypes = {
    registerBidder: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
  };



  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const {
      email,
      password,
      password2,
      first_name,
      last_name,
      aluno
    } = this.state;
    if (password != password2) {
      this.props.createMessage({
        passwordNotMatch: "Passwords não são iguais"
      });
    } else {
      const newUser = {
        email,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        password,
        aluno
      };
      this.props.registerBidder(newUser);
    }
  };
  handleChange = () => {
    if (this.state.aluno == "false") {
      this.setState({ aluno: "true" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ aluno: "false" });
    }
  };
  onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    render() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated && this.registerBidder) {
      return <Redirect to="/dashboardBidder" />;
    }

    const { email, password, password2, first_name, last_name } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <div className="card card-body mt-5">
          <h2 className="text-center">Register</h2>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                name="email"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={email}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>First Name</label>
              <input
                type="name"
                className="form-control"
                name="first_name"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={first_name}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Last Name</label>
              <input
                type="name"
                className="form-control"
                name="last_name"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={last_name}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                name="password"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={password}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Confirm Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                name="password2"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={password2}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="react__checkbox">
              <label>Aluno</label>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                className="react__checkbox--input"
                aluno={this.state.aluno}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                Register
              </button>
            </div>
            <p>
              Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { registerBidder, createMessage })(RegisterBidder);
```

My action to register.

```
export const registerBidder = ({
  email,
  first_name,
  last_name,
  password,
  aluno
}) => dispatch => {
  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

  // Request Body
  const body = JSON.stringify({
    user: { email, first_name, last_name, password },
    aluno: aluno
  });
  console.log(body);
  dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });
  axios
    .post("/api/auth/registar/bidder", body, config)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_FAIL
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: It would be helpful if your question was clearly stated.

Comment: Could you attach a codesandbox demo??